# How to print a list of tupled tuples in CSV-acceptable format?

Tags: python

I have a list of tuples I would like to print in CSV format without quotes or brackets.

```
[(('a','b','c'), 'd'), ... ,(('e','f','g'), 'h')]
```

Desired output:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h
```

I can get rid of some of the punctuation using chain, .join() or the *-operator, but my knowledge is not sophisticated enough to get rid of all of it for my particular use case.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So, in your case there is a pattern which makes this relatively easy:

```
>>> x = [(('a','b','c'), 'd') ,(('e','f','g'), 'h')]
>>> [c for a,b in x for c in (*a, b)]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
```

Or, an `itertools.chain` solution:

```
>>> list(chain.from_iterable((*a, b) for a,b in x))
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
>>>
```

And, in case you are on an old version of Python, and can't use `(*a, b)` you will need something like:

```
[c for a,b in x for c in a+(b,)]
```

Comment: Immensely helpful, thank you!